# Prove that a group $G$ has a faithful irreducible representation over a field $F$ if and only if the centre of $G$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory, cyclic-groups

An answer to this question would be greatly appreciated.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $F$ a field such that the order $\mid G\mid$ is coprime to the characteristic of $F$. Prove that $G$ has a faithful irreducible representation over $F$ if and only if the centre of $G$ is cyclic

Comment: Can you do either direction yourself?

Comment: I only know that if V is a faithful irreducible $FG$-module and $F=\mathbb{C}$ then the centre is cyclic.

Comment: The same proof works for for any algebraically closed field $F$. If $F$ is not algebraically closed then embed it into an algebraically closed field, and the representation will decompose into a sum of algebraically conjugate representations, which all have the same kernel, so they must all be faithful. Hence the centre is cyclic, which deals with that direction. The other direction is much more difficult. See  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57129